# How can I link production code and test code by using sonarQube, maven, or other tools?

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, junit, sonarqube

I want to know how to link production code and test code, i.e., I'd like to answer this question: which product codes are the targets of this test code?
I'd like to do this automatically.
My project uses maven and I have used SonarQube and the source codes are written in Java.
If it's needed, I will try any other tools.
How can I link production codes and test codes?
Please let me know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is effectively getting the **Coverage** of your tests, an answer to the question "What lines/branches of my code are **covered** by my tests?".

Maven and SonarQube are perfectly suited for this, the only thing you need to add into the mix is **Jacoco**. A good explanation for the configuration of Jacoco/Junit is [here](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/maven/creating-code-coverage-reports-for-unit-and-integration-tests-with-the-jacoco-maven-plugin/). Jacoco is an [agent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html) that gets added to the execution of your tests and which monitors them, analyzing which lines/branches have been executed (covered) and which have not.

The important part is to configure the jacoco plugin and the surefire/failsafe plugin(s) (last one is for integration tests) to use jacoco. This will generate jacoco report files, which then can/will be read by SonarCube during the `sonar:sonar` goal (you might have to set the path to these files either in your maven pom.xml as a sonar property or directly in the SonarQube server properties, both work fine).

You can test it step-by-step, first getting jacoco to run, since it already creates nice html reports. Reading the reports into SonarQube is the easier part then.

Comment: Thank you for giving me the advice!!
However, I exactly want to know which test codes test which product codes to improve the software quality.
For example, there is a product code with low test coverage and there are hundreds of unit test code.
Then, a question rises: Which test code tests this product code?
Without answering this question, I can't improve the coverage of the product code, right?